# apk crashes in background when no internet connection

Tags: android, service, crash, internet-connection

I had developed a small application which is running fine while having internet connection. But crashes when lost internet connection. I had implemented

1. Asynctask to fetch information from server and to display
2. Service which continuously monitor for the new message and gives notification if it found a new one. It run for every minute.
3. Declared min-sdk and target-sdk to 8 in the Manifest file.

Can anyone help me out of this ?? I am not getting an issue weather its an AsyncTask  or API level.

Answer (score 0):

use try and catch to handle the exception like this:

```
try
{
    MyService.CallFunction();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //Show an error Message
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but still facing the same problem. My apk crashes on phone after sometime while running. I runs properly on emulator and on lower API.

Comment: then let us have a look on your code.
Did you tried to debug the app on your phone to see what exception is raised?

Comment: @kedritch- actually I am not getting an error at particular activity. I have tested the whole app, its running fine. But when I minimize and disable internet it crashes saying "Application has unfortunately stopped".

Comment: I would like to suggest you to implement ACRA (https://github.com/ACRA/acra) into your application, and to see where exactly it is crashed. Then you can investigate the details.